# PetFinder API CORS Issue

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, cors

I'm using PetFinder's API (https://www.petfinder.com/developers/api-docs) to grab some photos of dogs. Their API is pretty simple. My issue is CORS. I have a Chrome extension that tells Chrome to not bother so I can view my work locally but I would like it if I could throw this to GitHub pages or share it with someone else and they could just clone it and run it.

I built the app using `create-react-app`. Basically it's a fetch request. I can do it with simple JSON or I can add `&callback=?` to grab their JSONP. I've done some digging about including a second argument with info to bypass CORS but I can't stick the landing. If the server-side doesn't have their HEADERS correct am I just stuck with a potentially opaque response? Is there a better way to do this with the JSONP? Can someone tell me my options?

```
componentDidMount() {
  fetch('http://api.petfinder.com/pet.find?key=superSecretKeyForMeToKnow&animal=dog&location=94103&output=full&format=json')
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(petFinderJson => this.setState({ dogs: petFinderJson.petfinder.pets.pet }));
}
```

Comment: You need a proxy.

Comment: @Baruch Yeah I saw something about that. Add `proxy: api.petfinder.com` to the package.json file? Or something else?

Comment: You could do that, but I recommend using `setupProxy.js` as described here: https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/proxying-api-requests-in-development#configuring-the-proxy-manually

Answer (score 0):

Baruch was right. I needed a proxy.

I simply needed to added `"proxy": "http://api.petfinder.com"` to the `package.json` and then modify the fetch request to preclude that line. so  `www.google.com/search` would become `/search` in the fetch request!

Did the trick! Woo!